# 'A' or 'an' against optional (bracketed) part?

Tags: indefinite-articles, parentheses

If I have a statement : "She provides a (easy) path to information," should I use *a* or *an* ?

I know I could re-write the optional adjective to be something that starts with a consonant sound, i.e.? "She provides a (simple) path to information," but in my case it must be the word *easy,* which starts with a vowel sound.

Does the article follow the optional or the formal declaration, i.e., 'information?' Or is it not allowed, and the sentence MUST be rewritten?